# How to unconditionally count the number of cell in a given range in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

How to unconditionally count number of cell in Excel?  Can we do this in one function?  For example, F(A1:D3) always return 12.

Answer (score 1):

**Assumption:** By "unconditionally", I assume that you don't want to use `IF`, `COUNTIF`, `COUNTIFS`, etc functions.

You can use both `COUNTA` and `COUNTBLANK` functions to achieve it. Sum the results of the mentioned functions to get the number of selected cells in the range.

```
=COUNTA(A1:D3)+COUNTBLANK(A1:D3)
```

[image]

Comment: ...or just `=ROWS(A1:D3)*COLUMNS(A1:D3)`

Comment: @JohnSUN Correct.

Comment: Thank you very much @ReddyLutonadio

Comment: Thank you very much @JohnSUN